# Input() to Allow <Enter Key> to Insert New Line Instead Of Returning Out of the Code in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am new to Python so please explain any code you write!

I want an `input()` to terminate after 1 blank line to allow for more than one line.

For example, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while using `input()`, I want it to go onto the next line, but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, it returns out of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
quit = False

while not quit:
    d = input()
    print(d)
    if d == '': quit = True
```

or

```
while True:
    d = input()
    if d == '': break
    print(d)
```